# How to iterate through an array of objects containing another nested array of objects using map() function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

How should I iterate through an array of objects in JavaScript using the map() function? I am doing this:

```
const arr = [
{title: "Title 1", url: "/title1"},
{title: "Title 2", url: "/title2"},
{title: "Title 3", url: "/title3"},
{title: "Title 4", url: "/title4"},
]

arr.map((item, index)=>{
return(

<li key={index}>
<a href={item.url}>{{item.title}}</a>
</li>

)
})
```

This works fine but what about if I have an array of objects with a nested array of objects? Like,

```
const arr = [
{title: "Title 1", url: "/title1"},
{title: "Title 2", url: "/title2"},
{title: "Title 3", url: "/title3"},
{title: "Title 4", url: "/title4", subs:[
{title: "Title 1", url: "/title1"},
{title: "Title 2", url: "/title2"},
{title: "Title 3", url: "/title3"},
]},
{title: "Title 5", url: "/title5"},
{title: "Title 6", url: "/title6"},
]
```

Expected Output:

```
Title 1
Title 2
Title 3
Title 4
  - Title 1
  - Title 2
  - Title 3
Title 5
Title 6
```

**My Approach**

I write following piece of code to get the expected results but having an error `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')`.

```
arr.map((item, index)=>{
return(
<ul>
<li key={index}>
<Link href={item.url}>{item.title}</Link>
</li>

{item.subs.map((topic, index)=>{
return(
<li key={index}>
<Link href={topic.url}>{topic.title}</Link>
</li>

)
})}
</ul>
)
})
```

**Please Write me piece of code that works**

Comment: Check for a `subs` property while mapping the parent array. If there is one, map that property using the same logic.

Comment: Yes. But there are many questions about how to do this on this site and others. I would appreciate you trying things out yourself.

Comment: and if you try something and doesn't work for you, then edit your question with your attempt and we can help you debug

Comment: Questions edited. Please review it now.

Comment: Thank you, everybody. I solved my problem by using the `if` statement if the object has the property of `subs` then continue. I used  `hasOwnProperty('subs')` method.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a suitable scenario for using a recursive function. Essentially, we can create a general function that calls itself. I have created the function for you. The function takes an array of elements, and iterates over each element. If the element has a "subs" array, it will call itself again and add the results to the "element" variable. If there are no "subs" in the current element, it will simply add it to the current element.

On another note, there is an alternative method to accomplish this without recursion by utilizing an array of dependencies. If you would like, I can also construct this method for you.

```
const arr = [
    { title: "Title 1", url: "/title1" },
    { title: "Title 2", url: "/title2" },
    { title: "Title 3", url: "/title3" },
    {
      title: "Title 4",
      url: "/title4",
      subs: [
        { title: "Title NEST 1", url: "/title1" },
        {
          title: "Title NEST 2",
          url: "/title2",
          subs: [{ title: "Title NEST  NEST X", url: "/titleX" }],
        },
        { title: "Title NEST 3", url: "/title3" },
      ],
    },
  ];
  function arrToElement(arr: Array<any>): JSX.Element {
    debugger;
    let element = (
      <>
        <div>root is here</div>
      </>
    );
    for (const i in arr) {
      const index = parseInt(i);
      // when there is subs
      if (arr[index].subs) {
        element = (
          <>
            <div>
              {element}
              <br />
              plus
              {index}
              <div>
                {arr[index].title} nested <div></div>
                --{arrToElement(arr[index].subs)}
              </div>
            </div>
          </>
        );
      }
      else {
        element = (
          <>
            <div>
              {element}
              <br />
              plus
              {index}
              <div>
                {arr[index].title} not nested
              </div>
            </div>
          </>
        );
      }
    }
    return element;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are probably better of with a recursive function to achieve what you are looking for.

**ReactJS:**

```
const RenderNested = ({ items }) => {
  return (
    <ul>
      {items.map((item, index) => (
        <li key={index}>
          {item.title}
          {item.subs && <RenderNested items={item.subs} />}
        </li>
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
};


export function App(props) {
  return (
    <div>
      <RenderNested items={arr} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

1. `RenderNested` takes a property called items, that is an array.
2. `RenderNested` starts to render our unordered list by looping over it as a map.
3. If we find an object container subs-object, we recursively call `RenderNested` that starts over at step 1.
4. Once no more items, we end our unordered list and return.

Same concept with ***Vanilla* JavaScript**:

```
const renderNested = (items) => {
  let render = '<ul>';
  items.forEach((item) => {
    render += '<li>';
    render += item.title;
    if (item.subs) {
      render += '<ul>';
      render += renderNested(item.subs);
      render += '</ul>';
    }
    render += '</li>';
  });
  render += '</ul>';
  return render;
};


const list = document.getElementById("list");
list.innerHTML = renderNested(arr);
```

Since it is recursive, you can basically have as many levels of nested lists you need or want.